# Adding multiple images on a page with CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, model-view-controller, crud

I want to add several different images with a crud to make some "work pages" but i struggle with the way to do this. Do I have to update my model or how i can specify that each adding field is for a section of my view? I'm using cloudinary to host the images.

For now when I add an image its all the same but I wanted to add differents ones at each spot.

My work#new view :

```
<div class="container text center">
  <%= simple_form_for(@work) do |f| %>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="heading-02" style="padding: 2rem 0rem;">New Work</h1>
        <div class="work-new-section">
          <h2 class="sub-heading-03">Header</h2>
          <%= f.input :name %>

          <%= f.input :description %>

          <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
        </div>
        <div class="work-new-section">
          <h2 class="sub-heading-03">Tasks</h2>
          <%= f.input :task_title %>

          <%= f.input :tasks %>

          <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>

        </div>
        <div class="work-new-section">
          <h2 class="sub-heading-03">Content#1</h2>
          <%= f.input :content1_title %>

          <%= f.input :content1 %>

          <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
        </div>
        <div class="work-new-section">
          <h2 class="sub-heading-03">Focus</h2>
          <%= f.input :focus_title %>

          <%= f.input :focus %>

        </div>
        <div class="work-new-section">
          <h2 class="sub-heading-03">Content#2</h2>
          <%= f.input :content2_title %>

          <%= f.input :content2 %>

          <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Create a new Work', :class => 'button-accent mb-4' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[Work#new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFCha.png)

My Work model :

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

For the work#show is use some partials with the same behaviour in it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <%= cl_image_tag @work.photo.key, :class=> "work-image", :width => 420, :height => 236, :crop => "fill"  %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <h2 class="sub-heading-03"><%= @work.content1_title %></h2>
      <p class="ui-regular-01"><%= @work.content1 %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Work#show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MocJS.jpg)

How could I specify one particular photo to each section? (task, content#1, content#2 etc...)

Thank you very much for your time!

I tried to change my new view but i have the impression that i omit something that i don't understand very well.

Comment: You're trying to do a job which should be done by many different models with just one model. You need to go back to the drawing board and figure out how you're going to add Section, Task etc models to the picture and how you're going to create assocations between the models and how you're going to accept nested attributes for these models.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I created a new Task model which depends to my Works model. I hope I could handle the tasks controller ^^